# Email notification via WP_Mail on published custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-mail

I've been trying to get an email notification to fire when a new custom post type (in this case, "event"), is published. I've tried a few things and settled down to this simple example that, I imagine, *should* work just fine.

```
function admin_event_notification()
{

   $message = "Test";
   wp_mail( 'jonathan@sabramedia.com', 'New Event', $message );


}
add_action( 'new_event', 'admin_event_notification', 10, 3 );
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Once that works, the next step is accessing $post to get the title and permalinks, etc. I think I've got that covered, but any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Where do you hook your function? Is there action like - new_{custom_post_type}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'new_event'` is not a default wordpress hook. Hence the above will only work if you include `do_action( 'new_event' );` in your custom post type's saving/publishing function.

Your usage of [`wp_mail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) is otherwise correct.

See [the codex on `do_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) for reference.